# Autocompletion of module name as function parameter

Tags: typescript, import

In a Typescript project I get autocompletion of the module name when typing `import foo from "[autocompletion available]"`. I want to create a function now that can get a module name and also get the same autocompletion as when using the import statement:

```
function customImport(moduleName: T) {
  ...
}

customImport("[autocompletion here]")
```

Is this possible, maybe with some special type T?